# How can I obtain a Mule ARM registration token to be used to register a server into AMC

Tags: mule

I was reading at
https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/apiplatform/anypoint-platform/#/portals/organizations/ae639f94-da46-42bc-9d51-180ec25cf994/apis/38784/versions/127446/pages/182856

because I want to automate Anypoint Runtime Manager enablement on lots of servers.
My plan is to use REST to get the proper registration token to be used to register a server into AMC. There are directions on the page:

To register a server you must first authenticate against the Anypoint Platform Authentication Manager and get an authentication token, with this token you need to obtain a registration token to be used to register a server into AMC.

I understand the first part and can get the authentication token, but I can't find a reference to how to get the registration token.

How can I get this token?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you seen the [Obtain the Server Registration Token](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/managing-servers#obtaining-the-server-registration-token) part in the documentation?

take a look [here](https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/apiplatform/anypoint-platform/#/portals/organizations/ae639f94-da46-42bc-9d51-180ec25cf994/apis/38784/versions/127446/pages/182845), if you want to obtain a registration token by calling the REST API. There is a API endpoint called `/servers/registrationToken`

Comment: I have, but that is how to do it without REST. I want to get the token using REST so that I don't have to login. I am writing a script where I will pass in the environment name, and domain name and it will login and find the token to use and then use it.

Comment: are u sure there is a API for that?

Comment: I am not sure, but the text sounds promising: To register a server you must first authenticate against the Anypoint Platform Authentication Manager and get an authentication token, with this token you need to obtain a registration token to be used to register a server into AMC.

Comment: you are probably right. [Here](https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/apiplatform/anypoint-platform/#/portals/organizations/ae639f94-da46-42bc-9d51-180ec25cf994/apis/38784/versions/127446/pages/182845) the documentation mentions a API endpoint named `/servers/registerationToken`

Answer (score 1):

You can also get a registration token with the new anypoint-cli v2.x. This will combine several REST API calls for you. The command is:

```
runtime-mgr server token
```

You can type this in the interactive shell, or add this to the end of a stand-alone call from your favorite scripting environment. For example, if you have created a profile with your ANYPOINT_USERNAME, ANYPOINT_PASSWORD, and ANYPOINT_ORG, and ANYPOINT_ENV, you can then call:

```
anypoint-cli runtime-mgr server token
```

You can find the docs and installation instructions here: docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/anypoint-platform-cli#runtime-mgr-server-token.

If you want to do this directly with the REST API, you'll have to make several calls:

1. POST a core services access_token from 
   anypoint.mulesoft.com/accounts/login
   with the username and password in the BODY as a JSON object.

   curl -X POST \
     anypoint.mulesoft.com/accounts/login \
     -H 'content-type: application/json' \
     -d '{
       "username":"yourUserName",
       "password":"yourPassword"
   }'

Store the response as a variable (let's call it {{access_token}}.

2. Copy this access_token in the header for every other API call: Key: Authorization, Value: bearer {{access_token}}
3. Obtain or store the organization ID in which you want to register the server. There's several ways to do this. The value is available via a GET request to

   anypoint.mulesoft.com/accounts/api/me

   curl -X GET \
     anypoint.mulesoft.com/accounts/api/me \
     -H 'authorization: bearer aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa'

You might want to use the JQ libraries to parse the organizationID from this JSON response.

4. Get the environment ID for the environment in which you want to register the Mule runtime (server) from a GET request to:

   anypoint.mulesoft.com/accounts/api/organizations/{{organizationId}}/environments

   curl -X GET \
     https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/accounts/api/organizations/bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb/environments \
     -H 'authorization: bearer aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa' \
     -H 'content-type: application/json'
5. Make a GET request to 
   anypoint.mulesoft.com/hybrid/api/v1/servers/registrationToken

With the headers X-ANYPNT-ORG-ID and X-ANYPNT-ENV-ID set:

```
curl -X GET \
  anypoint.mulesoft.com/hybrid/api/v1/servers/registrationToken \
  -H 'authorization: bearer aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa' \
  -H 'x-anypnt-env-id: cccccccc-cccc-cccc-cccc-cccccccccccc' \
  -H 'x-anypnt-org-id: bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb'
```

This will return a registration token.

Then use this registration token with the amc_setup -H command

amc_setup -H {{registration_token}} *Server-Name*